Can complicated $\mathcal{Q} (\theta; \theta^{\text{old}})$ function be replaced by log-likelihood when implementing/coding EM algorithm?
I am working on a MLE problem where one of the parameters does not have a closed-form solution. I have a proposal for $\theta^{\text{new}}$, but reject it if it does not improve $\mathcal{Q} (\theta; \theta^{\text{old}})$. In my case, $\mathcal{Q} (\theta; \theta^{\text{old}})$ is very complicated and too difficult for me to code/evaluate.
To summarize the relevant part of the algorithm, it looks like this:

If $\mathcal{Q} (\theta; \theta^{\text{proposal}}) 
 \geq \mathcal{Q} (\theta; \theta^{\text{old}})$, then assign $\theta^{\text{new}} \longleftarrow \theta^{\text{proposal}}$.

I have to evaluate the $\mathcal Q$ function to check if the proposal is good. Can I instead check if my proposal improves the model log-likelihood $\mathcal{L} (\theta \,|\, X )$? That is, could I replace part of the algorithm as:

If $\mathcal{L} (\theta^{\text{proposal}} \,|\, X) 
 \geq \mathcal{L} (\theta^{\text{old}} \,|\, X)$, then assign $\theta^{\text{new}} \longleftarrow \theta^{\text{proposal}}$.


The associated algorithm sees the likelihood increasing, hence it shares the same feature as the EM algorithm. An alternative is to use one gradient step, assume $\nabla_\theta Q(\theta;\theta^\text{old})$ is available in some format.

See eg this conference paper by Salakhutdinov, Roweis and Ghahramani
